# natbib - bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

After some research I found the bibliographystyle "humannat". It does look exactly the way I was looking for, except the new line after "Name, First Name"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{humannat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}

book \cite[22]{Radatz.1980}

\medskip

\bibliography{Test}

\end{document}
```

How can I get rid of  this extra line? I'm not sure if I have to redefine \bibitem or humannat. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy `humannat.bst` as `humannat-mod.bst` in the same directory as your main TeX file.

Open it with any text editor and change the two occurrences of

```
"\leavevmode\nopagebreak\newline"
```

into

```
" "
```

Then change `\bibliographystyle{humannat}` into `\bibliographystyle{humannat-mod}`, rerun LaTeX and BibTeX, then LaTeX again.

[image]

To get parentheses around the year, go to line 155 in `humannat-mod.bst` to find

```
%      " (" year * extra.label * ")" *
      " " year * extra.label *           % for humannature
```

Exchange the position of the `%`, to get

```
      " (" year * extra.label * ")" *
%      " " year * extra.label *           % for humannature
```

You'll get

[image]

Changing the period to a colon would require major surgery. Better going with `biblatex` if you need to customize reference lists.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. One last question: What do I have to change to get "Riter, W. (2013):" instead of "Riter, W. 2013"?

Comment: @ulead86 My advice is to go with `biblatex` that allows for easier customizations. Anyway, I added the parentheses, but not the colon.

Comment: Thanks a lot so far, I'll definitly have a look at biblatex.