# How to change Natbib style to a custom format/Bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

Part 1 of the problem:

I need the bibliography to cite like:

> LastName, First letter of first name (year of publication). Title. Place: publisher

the closest i got was using the humannat style but that isn't good enough.

Part 2 of the Problem:
I also do not know how to accomplish complex Citations like from anthologies. I need to do it like:

> Ulm V. Title of text. In Füchter A., Moegling K. (Hrsg.), Title of Anthology. Place: publisher. Sites of the text.

I really have no clue how to achieve something like that. Normally i write anything i latex but without your help i am afraid that i would have to use word...

Comment: You mention `natbib` in the title and tagged the question with `natbib` and `biblatex`. Do you want to use `natbib` or would you be OK with `biblatex` as well?

Comment: I only worked with natbib until now but if you got great ideas i am open to switch

Comment: If you only want `humannat` with parentheses https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253052/35864 might help.

Answer (score 1):

With `biblatex` many small modifications to styles are fairly straightforward. [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) gives a short overview over the most common changes.

The standard styles print the name of `editor`s after the `booktitle` for `@inbook` and `@incollection`, so I based the answer on my style bundle [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext), where you can easily move the name with the option `innamebeforetitle=true`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber,
           giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
           innamebeforetitle=true]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,gaonkar:in,westfahl:space}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: Gaonkar, D. P. (2001). ‘On Alternative Modernities’. In: Gaonkar, D. P. (ed.), Alternative Modernities. Durham and London: Duke University Press, pp. 1–23. isbn: 0-822-32714-7.//Sigfridsson, E., Ryde, U. (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395.// Westfahl, G. (2000). ‘The True Frontier. Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American Science Fiction Films’. In: Westfahl, G. (ed.), Space and Beyond. The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction. Westport, Conn. and London: Greenwood, pp. 55–65.]

Comment: That seems to not work for me... It says \cite is not defined...

Also could you give me your .bib file so i could see how it handles anthologies?

Comment: @TomGöbel If LaTeX complains about `\cite` not being defined there should be other earlier errors as well. Did you run the example exactly as posted or did you try to implement the change in your document already? `biblatex-examples.bib` is part of every LaTeX distribution that has `biblatex` installed. If you can't find it on your machine you can download it from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib or view it at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib

Comment: i copied your exact code. Here's the project: https://www.overleaf.com/4861456139ytssmpdqgxzb

Comment: @TomGöbel Aha! Overleaf does not have `biblatex-ext` installed. The package is too new.

Comment: I think i just go back to word... This is just way too much work for a little less tilt because of word. Thanks anyways!